# When to declare member method in C#

Tags: c#

This is my situation: ( This is an controller of ASP.net MVC 5 )

```
public class Class1
{
    public Class1()
    {
    }

    public void MethodA()
    {
        UserBLL bll = new UseBLL();
        // some code that call method from bll
    }

    public void MethodB()
    {
        UserBLL bll = new UseBLL();
        // some code that call method from bll
    }
}
```

I use the UseBLL two times. ( it may ten more times ). So that I think I should declare an object member like this.

```
public class Class1
{
    UserBLL bll;
    public Class1()
    {
        bll = new UseBLL();
    }

    public void MethodA()
    {

        // some code that call method from bll
    }

    public void MethodB()
    {
        // some code that call method from bll
    }
}
```

Is it an wise decision ? If not, why ?

Should I change  `UserBLL bll;` to  `UserBLL bll {set;get };`  ( When I need to do this ? )

Thanks for all helping :)

Comment: *Is it an wise decision* yes, to avoid repeating yourself. *Should I change UserBLL bll; to UserBLL bll {set;get }; ( When I need to do this ? )* that depends on if and how you want to use this class outside of `Class1`

Comment: If `UserBLL` does anything meaningful, consider injecting it and not manually creating it at all (read up on inversion of control, if you are not familiar with it).

Comment: @TimCastelijns: it not functionally equivalent, hence you cannot say that it's a wise decision in general. If you use a field in two methods you use the same object, if you create a new instance in both methods you use two different objects.

Comment: Your question might be better suited for [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 3):

It depends. :)

Things you need to consider are:

- State (does `UserBLL` maintain state and do you or don't you want that kept around?)
- Thread safety (could multiple threads access it at the same time and cause corruption?)
- How expensive is it to create?

However, my typical approach here would be to apply the Dependency Inversion principle. That means `UserBLL` would implement an interface, and when creating an instance of `Class1`, a class implementing `IUserBLL` would be supplied and stored in a `private readonly` field by the constructor.

Example:

```
public class Class1
{
    private readonly IUserBLL _userBll;

    public Class1(IUserBLL userBll)
    {
        // Null checks here...
        _userBll = userBll;
    }

    public void Method()
    {
        _userBll.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

You still need to take the first two points above into consideration, but now you have a consistent approach and you don't need to worry about what exactly `_userBll` is, and can change it without affecting `Class1`.

Typically this scenario of objects being injected into constructors is implemented using an IoC container (sometimes referred to as a "DI container" or "DI framework").

So follow-up reading:

- Dependency Inversion Principle
- Inversion of Control container (example: Ninject, Castle.Windsor, StructureMap, Autofac).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it seems like a good idea to put `bll` on the class level.

Since you made it `private` (implicitly), which is also a good idea, it is fine to have just a field, as you did; you seem to not need a property (`get` and `set`).

I suggest you mark your field as `readonly` since you only want to assign to it in the instance constructor(s).

As was said in a comment to your question, you might also consider letting the instance constructor take in a parameter, as in:

```
public class Class1
{
    readonly UserBLL bll;
    public Class1(UserBLL bll)
    {
        this.bll = bll;
    }

    // ...
```

or maybe:

```
public class Class1
{
    readonly UserBLL bll;
    public Class1(UserBLL bll)
    {
        this.bll = bll;
    }
    public Class1() : this(new UserBLL())
    {
    }

    // ...
```

Comment: " you might also consider letting the instance constructor take in a parameter, as in:"  Why I should do this ? :)

Comment: @user2877989 You don't *have* to do this, but I thought it might be useful as a simple kind of [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#Constructor_injection). If you don't need it, you can simply assign the `readonly` field directly at its declaration (field initializer), so you won't even have to mention it explicitly in the constructor(s).

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting to use the UserBLL a lot exposing it may have some advantages, mainly easier access. But I would be careful with exposing the setter as the client using your main class will be able to change it. You can prevent it using only getter:

```
private UserBLL _Bll;
internal UserBLL Bll
{
    get
    {
        return _Bll;
    }
}
```

However if external use of the methods from the UserBLL happens only in a limited number of cases (like the two methods you've presented) AND you need to modify the result of the UserBLL using data from your class then exposing the UserBLL through methods in your class is a more practical decisions.

To wrap it up, your decision should depend on:

1) level of exposure you want to have of UserBLL
2) level of interaction between UserBLL and Class1

Comment: What you wanted to do in your code example can also be achieved with an auto-property with "asymmetric" accessibility, i.e. `internal UserBLL Bll { get; private set; }`. Your code is an illegal hybrid between a method and a property.

Comment: fixed that declaration, but your auto-property might be the even cleaner solution iif the backing store should not be declared readonly (see other answers)

Answer (score 0):

This seems not to be a technical problem but a conceptual one.
A class represents the definition of your object as you know, and in this case you have to ask yourself few questions :

- Does the UserBLL class belong to class1 or to method ?
- Do you need to use UserBLL when you create an object from your class ?

Like

```
Class1 c = new Class1();
c.UserBll.MethodA(...)
```

- Does the UserBLL is only use in the method and will not be reused ?
- ...

If you declare your UserBLL as a property of the class, UserBLL will belong to the class.
Think conception and use and you'll know how you have to design your classes.

In your case, if you use UserBLL class in all your method, I think you could add it as a property, if you need it outside the method of your class you can put it in public with get, otherwise private,  if you need it to be changed by another method than those in your classe you could add set in your property...